# How to calculate a growing or decreasing percentage between rows usign group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's suposse that I have this table_1:

```
Year Item Qty_sold
2013 1    3
2013 2    2
2013 3    5
2014 1    2
2014 2    3
```

I'll perform something like this

```
select year , sum(Qty_sold) as Quantity
from table_1 inner join table_2 on .... inner join table_n
where Year = 2014
```

The final result depends mostly on the filter by year, but there are other tables involved.

But as a result I need something like this:

```
Year Quantity  Diff_Percentage
2014 5         0.5
```

Because during the previous year (2013) the final quantity of items sold was 10.

Regards

Comment: Traditionally using a CTE or join back on the table is the way to go,

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment. Maybe I simplified too much the query. The inner joins between tables can produce an elevated number of rows as an answer, and maybe the memory can not be enough to perform a CTE..

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select year, sum(Qty_sold) as Quantity,
       lag(sum(qty_sold)) over (order by year) as prev_Quantity,
       (1 - Quantity / lag(sum(qty_sold)) over (order by year)) as diff_percentage
from table
group by Year;
```

Of course, this returns the info for all years.  If you really just want the year 2014 and 2013 then use conditional aggregation:

```
select year,
       sum(case when year = 2014 then Qty_sold end) as Quantity_2014,
       sum(case when year = 2013 then Qty_sold end) as Quantity_2013,
       (1 - sum(case when year = 2014 then Qty_sold end)/
            sum(case when year = 2013 then Qty_sold end) 
       ) as diff_percentage
from table
where Year in (2013, 2014);
```

I'm sort of guessing on the formula for `diff_percentage`, but I think that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your replay but I am getting some problems with the query. As an answer I have two records, one for every year, and at the end if I try to calculate the division I receive and error message: division by 0.

Comment: @d2907 . . . These queries should not generate error messages due to the division -- unless the quantity sold is explicitly zero.  There is no `else` clause, so the default value would be `NULL` if there are no matches.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, please try this

```
select t.year,qty, (1-qty/prev_qty)
from
(select year, sum(Qty_sold) as qty,
       lag(sum(qty_sold)) over (order by year) as prev_qty
from tbl group by Year) t where t.year=in_year --in_year whichever year record you want.
```

Hope it works for you.